CustomTicks package not working in Mathematica 14.1
I noticed that using the same syntax for the "CustomTicks package" as in Mathematica 13 doesn't work in Mathematica 14.1.
For example, in Mathematica 13 the working syntax was:
Needs["CustomTicks`"]
SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.030, 0}, 
 MinorTickLength -> {0.015, 0}, MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.004], 
 MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.002]];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x,y},FrameTicks -> {{None, LinTicks}, {None, None}}]

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

You may need to re-install it? Do you not get an error when calling Needs?
If you haven't tried already , you can migrate your settings to 14.1
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MigrateSettingsToWolframApp/

After playing around for a while, it seems that the package works within Mathematica 14.1 if the installation syntax Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mark-caprio/CustomTicks/master/CustomTicks.m"] is placed specifically within the given notebook file.
